# Omit specified field in collection while fetching it from mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database in mongodb, however, there's some field (`userEmail`) in every collection, that I dont want to fetch it to the client side.

I expect it to be something like:

```
User.find(callback)
    .limit(limit)
    .omit('userEmail');
```

I couldnt find it anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-all-but-the-excluded-fields) to limit your fields

```
User.find(callback).project({ userEmail: 0 }).limit(limit)
```